# Why is the core i7 only showing 4 cores on Ubuntu 16 with the latest Kernel?

Tags: intel, cpu

Why is the Core i7-7500 CPU@2.70GHZx4 only showing 4 cores on Ubuntu 16 with the latest Kernel?  Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series.  I have a System 76 laptop with a Core i7 and it shows 8 cores.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends upon exactly [which i7 processor](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i7-processors.html) is in the computer - also see the [i7 extreme](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i7-processor-extreme-edition.html) with upto 10 cores.

Also, I think most utilities count the number of threads rather than the number of physical cores - most of the I7 75xx series have 2 cores, and 4 threads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I should  have gone back to system 76, xyz company ran me around so many times plus they said they had drivers written for Ubuntu 16, I opened them up and they were .exe files.  There is supposed to be a way to convert to .deb.  I tried it before with no success.  Again thank you for your answer,.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I should  have gone back to system 76, xyz company ran me around so many times plus they said they had drivers written for Ubuntu 16, I opened them up and they were .exe files.  There is supposed to be a way to convert to .deb.  I tried it before with no success.  Again thank you for your answer.  Kabylake Intel Core i7-7500 CPU  @ 270GHZ x4.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into

system settings->details->overview

your core i7-7500 CPU@2.70GHZx4 should be correctly identified.

If you go into

system monitor-> resources

you should see the correct number of CPUs/threads.

This reporting would be true of any CPU that is installed in a mobo running Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   When did Intel stop using 7 virtual cores on the i7?

Comment: I just Goggled my own answer and found out the news is correct Core i7 only has 4 to 6 cores it's a bit deceptive IMHO.

Comment: You didn't find my answer useful or correct? :(

Comment: No just the opposite. I've been robed.  core i7 should not been used on the label if intel would have been honest, I would have had 8 cores not 4.  They lied just like a politician.  And the fact that they said they had windoz 7 drivers is another lie.  I will never do business with dell again, ever!!!   Worse than a politician.